# Why bother using ArrayList(int capacity)?

Tags: java, arraylist, benchmarking

So pretty much every question related to capacity in ArrayList is how to use it or (oddly) access it and I am quite familiar with that information.  What I am interested in whether it is actually worth using the ArrayList constructor that sets capacity if you happen to know or have a rough idea how many items will be in the ArrayList?

Are there any comprehensive benchmarks comparing how long it takes to just use naive adding of elements to an ArrayList versus pre-setting the capacity of an ArrayList?

Comment: When the capacity of the ArrayList is reached, CLR creates a new ArrayList with double the capacity of the original one and copies all the elements from the original one to the newly created one. Hence you can save this extra work by presetting the size of the ArrayList if you have some idea related to the size required.

Comment: @Deepansh: Isn't this a Java question? How did CLR come into picture? I guess you meant JVM? Also, your description seems correct but "in CLR" (.Net), it takes more time when I preallocate the size. Atleast, this is what happens when I tested it on 1000000 items. I tested it for 10-15 times and everytime the default ArrayList constructor won!

Comment: I said ArrayList, but it can apply to the concept in general of having a list view of a collection that is internally backed by an array.

Comment: Sorry Anthony, as ArrayList exists in .net also, I overlooked java tag. But I think the concept would be same in both .net and java.

Comment: @DeepanshGupta 'The details of the growth policy are not specified' for `ArrayList` but in practice the JDK uses a growth factor of 1.5, not 2.

Comment: Guys, `ArrayList` growth factor is 50%, i.e,. the size of an `ArrayList` increases by 50% after overflow. Check [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2001-06/03-qa-0622-vector.html) if you don't believe me.

Comment: @Anthony, I'm curious, are you certain default (no-args) constructor was faster than preallocating?  This goes exactly to my point, is there actually a comprehensive dataset out there that proves one way or the other?  I ask because recently, a good article pointed out that you should never used LinkedList because of the advantage locality of reference gives to ArrayList: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/340797/Why-you-should-never-ever-EVER-use-linked-list-in

Comment: @Maverick: Yes default constructor was faster than preallocating. I tested it with Stopwatch and found default one takes less time. I tested it on 1000000 items. However it is in C# so I didn't bother posting the program here.

Comment: @Anthony: I just tried that in Java, and on my system -- obviously this will be system-dependent -- but on my system, the version with preallocation was more than twice as fast, when I added a million `null`s, than the version without preallocation. (Obviously doing any sort of object construction will decrease the difference; when I tried adding `i`, where `i` was the loop variable, an `int` that had to get autoboxed, the version with preallocation was only about 25% faster, because `add` itself took a smaller proportion of the time.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Obviously for any specific application you'd have to test any performance adjustments to determine if they are in fact optimizations (and if they are in fact necessary), but there are some times that setting the capacity explicitly can be worthwhile. For example:

- You're creating a very large number of array-lists, most of which will be very small. In this case, you might want to set the initial capacity very low, and/or to trim the capacity whenever you're done populating a given array. (In this case, the optimization is less a matter of speed than of memory usage. But note that the list itself has memory overhead, as does the array it contains, so in this sort of situation it's likely to be better to redesign in such a way as to have fewer lists.)
- You're creating an array-list of a *very* large known size, and you want the time to add *each* element to be very small (perhaps because each time you add an element, you have to send some response to an external data-source). (The default geometric growth takes *amortized* constant time: every once in a while, a massive penalty is incurred, such that the overall average performance is completely fine, but if you care about individual insertions taken individually, that might not be good enough.)

Answer (score 3):

I have nothing substantial to add to ruakh's answer, but here's a quick test function. I keep a scrap project around for writing little tests like these.  Adjust the sourceSize to something representative of your data, and you can get a rough idea of the magnitude of the effect. As shown, I saw about a factor of 2 between them.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ALTest {
    public static long fill(ArrayList<Byte> al, byte[] source) {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (byte b : source) {
            al.add(b);
        }
        return System.currentTimeMillis()-start;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int sourceSize = 1<<20; // 1 MB
        int smallIter = 50;
        int bigIter = 4;

        Random r = new Random();
        byte[] source = new byte[sourceSize];
        for (int i = 0;i<bigIter;i++) {
            r.nextBytes(source);
            {
                long time = 0;
                for (int j = 0;j<smallIter;j++) {
                    ArrayList<Byte> al = new ArrayList<Byte>(sourceSize);
                    time += fill(al,source);
                }
                System.out.print("With: "+time+"ms\t");
            }
            {
                long time = 0;
                for (int j = 0;j<smallIter;j++) {
                    ArrayList<Byte> al = new ArrayList<Byte>();
                    time += fill(al,source);
                }
                System.out.print("Without: "+time+"ms\t");
            }
            {
                long time = 0;
                for (int j = 0;j<smallIter;j++) {
                    ArrayList<Byte> al = new ArrayList<Byte>();
                    time += fill(al,source);
                }
                System.out.print("Without: "+time+"ms\t");
            }
            {
                long time = 0;
                for (int j = 0;j<smallIter;j++) {
                    ArrayList<Byte> al = new ArrayList<Byte>(sourceSize);
                    time += fill(al,source);
                }
                System.out.print("With: "+time+"ms");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
With: 401ms Without: 799ms  Without: 731ms  With: 347ms
With: 358ms Without: 744ms  Without: 749ms  With: 342ms
With: 348ms Without: 719ms  Without: 739ms  With: 347ms
With: 339ms Without: 734ms  Without: 774ms  With: 358ms
```

Answer (score 1):

[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28int%29) internals uses simple arrays to store its elements, if the number of elements exceeds the capacity of the underlying array, a resize effort is need. So, in the case you know how many items will your List contain, you can inform ArrayList to use an array of the needed size so the resize logic won't be needed or executed.